# How to derive the equation for capacitive reactance?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, frequency

How to derive the equation for capacitive reactance $X_C$?

$$X_{C}=1/(2\pi fC)$$

with $f=$ frequency, and $C=$ capacitance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capacity $C$ of a capacitor is defined as: $$C = \frac{Q}{U} \Rightarrow Q = C \cdot U$$, where $Q$ is the charge on one side of the capacitor and $U$ is the voltage across the capacitor. Let's take the derivative with respect to time on both sides:

$$\frac{dQ}{dt} = I(t) = C \cdot \frac{dU}{dt}$$ where we use the fact that the derivative of the charge is the current.

Now if the voltage in the capacitor oscillates at a frequency $f$, which means $$U(t) = U_o \cdot \sin(2 \pi f t)$$ then the current will be: $$I(t) = C \cdot \frac{dU}{dt} = C \cdot U_o \cdot 2 \pi f \cdot \cos(2 \pi f t)$$ The capacitive reactance is defined as the ration between the amplitude of the voltage in a capacitor (in this case $U_o$) and the amplitude of the current in this capacitor (which is $C \cdot U_o \cdot 2 \pi f$). The capacitive reactance must therefor be: $$X_C = \frac{U_o}{C \cdot U_o \cdot 2 \pi f} = \frac{1}{2 \pi f C}$$

Comment: Thanks. The approach you came with is very simple. But I hope this approach can be used also for the inductive reactance?

Comment: Sure, simply start with $U(t) = L \frac{dI(t)}{dt}$ and use $I(t) = I_0 sin(2 \pi f t)$

Comment: Alright . Thanks again 